# Resize UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a 16x16 pixel image that I want to display in an UIImageView. So far, no problem, however 16x16 is a bit small so I want to resize the image view to 32x32 and thus also scale the image up.
But I can't get it to work, it always shows the image with 16x16, no matter what I try. I googled a lot, and found many snippets here on Stack Overflow, but its still doesn't work.
Here is my code so far:

```
[[cell.imageView layer] setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
[cell.imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[cell.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[cell.imageView setImage:image];
```

I don't want to create a new 32x32 pixel image because I already have some memory problems on older devices and creating two images instead of having just one looks like a very bad approach to me (the images can be perfectly scaled and it doesn't matter if they lose quality).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have successfully made it using CGAffineTransformMakeScale!

```
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
//self.rowWidth is the desired Width
//self.rowHeight is the desired height
CGFloat widthScale = self.rowWidth / cellImage.size.width;
CGFloat heightScale = self.rowHeight / cellImage.size.height;
//this line will do it!
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale);
```

Comment: This is a good, albeit duct-tape-y solution if you don't want to subclass UITableViewCell.

Comment: What is cellImage.size.width? I am using initWithStyle method

Comment: cellImage is a temp UIImageView used to calculate the width and height.

Comment: Great, but you need to set this first `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to set the contentMode:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

In context:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"slashdot" ofType:@"png"]];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,32,32)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;    
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Note: I've set a background colour so you can debug the on-screen boundaries of the UIImageView.  Also `x` and `y` are arbitrary integer coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it still doesn't work. If I create an UIImageView like you did, everything works fine, but the UIImageView from the UITableViewCell behaves different. I tested it also with another background color to verify that also the view itself still has an 16x16 frame.

Comment: Okay, looks like a UITableViewCell updates the frame anyway, no matter what I do. I'm now creating the labels and the UIImageView by myself and add them to the contentView of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CGAffineTransformMakeScele` as @ahmed said is valid and do not seems to be duck type solution at al! For instance, if you have a large image and put it into a UITableViewCell (say the image is 2x larger than the one that fits into a table cell. If you scale by 0.9 you don't see any result. Only if you scale by less than 0.5 (because 0.5*2.0 = 1.0 that is the size of the cell). So it seems that inside the api, apple is doing exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the layoutSubviews method. By default, it's resizing the imageview based on the cell height size.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,
                                      self.imageView.frame.origin.y,
                                      MY_ICON_SIZE,
                                      MY_ICON_SIZE);
}
```

You'll probably want to recalculate the origin as well so it's vertically centered.