# How to resize imageview of UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c

On UITableViewCell there is default imageview where we can set image on Cell. Now i want to resize or reframe the default imageview of UITableCell. I have used following code but there is no effects. I know it is possible if we use custom imageView. but i want to do for default imageview of cell.

```
[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 45, 45)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change size of default `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`, because it's readonly. Instead you can create your own `UITableViewCell` or add `UIImageView` as subview with any size you want

Comment: Not entirely true: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122958/resize-uiimageview-in-uitableviewcell