# Change ImageView Size of basic UITableView Cell in

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to display a TableView in Swift like this:

http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52428a0ae4b0c4a5c2a2cede/t/53ea627be4b0b0890925f7c8/1407869565104/?format=500w

I'm using the basic Table View Cell Type in my Prototype Cell. This works great so far. Only problem is, my pictures are just 50x50 px. But they are always scaled up to 80x80 px in the table view, and this looks pretty bad. I already tried to resize the ImageView of the TableView Cell in Code and in the Storyboard, but without success.

Is it possible to resize the ImageView of the basic Cell Type or do I have to create a custom Cell Type for this approach?

Comment: create custom cell as it best to handle rather than resizing

Comment: Try with custom cell in interface builder drag UIImageView in UITableViewCell and use this UIImageView in your code it will work. I had faced this kind of issue

Comment: I don't try this myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122958/resize-uiimageview-in-uitableviewcell

But hope this will help :)

Comment: Did it with custom cell style. Thanks for your comments